# C++ when to check exceptions of async method

Tags: c++, asynchronous, future

I'm stuck with executing a function async. For now the function is called synchronously. It stores some information on a list and provides information about the list items later.

```
// Read Infos
void MyManager::Read(HWND parent)
{
   // do some work...
   mItemInfos.push_back(info);
}

// provide information
ItemInfo* MyManager::GetInfo(int index)
{
  return mItemInfos.at(index);
}
```

Now I want to do the reading async. I defined a new method

```
void MyManager::BeginRead(HWND parent)
{
  mFuture = std::async(std::launch::async, &MyManager::Read, this, parent); 
}
```

Now when an exception is thrown in the `Read`method, i will never know, because the `mFuture.get()` method is never called. To fix this, should I just call `mFuture.get()` In `GetInfo()`? Everytime I call `GetInfo()`?

My whole approach seems to miss something, can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which type is mFuture? (std::future?)

Comment: @JVApen yes std::future, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, I see multiple issues:

- No mutexes around a std::vector while using it in multiple threads -> Race condition
- Assigning to the future will block your program
- You intend to call `.get()` multiple times on the same instance of future?

For `std::future` are only allowed to call `.get()` once. If you want to call it multiple times, you'll need `std::shared_future` which will throw every access.

So, should you call `.get()` before accessing the vector? Yes, definitely. Otherwise you don't have a guarantee that the element will be in the vector.
However, you should also add some synchronization for access of the vector, as one thread could try to access it, while another creates a new future which reallocates the vector you are accessing.

Finally, why do you waste time with creating new threads? The operation itself looks cheap. Even when it isn't, I can only assume you don't want to block at that point. Unfortunately, you don't prevent blocking as the Dtor of the `std::future` will block in certain cases.

Again, using `std::shared_future` would prevent that, however, than you no longer have control about whether it was executed, as the second assignment lets `mFuture` forget about the first one, even when not fully executed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right a mutex for the vector is needed and i already got one, but didnt mention it here. What I don't understand is why assigning the future will block my programm. I tested this code without assigning the future and that really blocked my programm. But once I assigned it a member variable, the function ran async. I didnt know I can only call `get()` once, and I should definatly call `get()` before accessing the vector, to make sure its there and valid, but I dont know how to exactly do that yet. Thank you so far